# Create custom SelectedIndices collection from existing SelectedRows collection in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, c#-3.0

I need to write a custom collection where it will store the selectedindices of the datagridview. Sine we have SelectedRows colllection property already present in Datagridview. I want to use it and get indices collection so that I can  I can create SelectedIndices as a custom property for my Datagridview which is of type collection. Can some one help m eon how will I do it.

For reference;
Selectedindices is a property of Listview provided by microsoft.I want the same with Datagridview. But since I don have that I want to use the SelectedRows property and an create a custom property Selectedindices for my datagridview. It should be of type Collection. PLease suggest if I can do the same .

Comment: Here at SO, we help those who help them self. When posting a question, we expect a little source code and some things you have tried. So, you can edit your question and add the necessary information to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that feature is already available, maybe you can find out more by view the link below?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedrowcollection.aspx

Also a little code sample of how far you got, or what you have tried already always entices other members to be more helpful.